# Shift from /sk/ → /ʃ/

Tags: phonetics

I'm not sure if this is a legitimate question to ask,but I noticed this sound change in a few germanic languages, such as Old English and German. How did it happen?

Comment: It's happened in Norwegian etc as well, but only in certain phonemic contexts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one form of [palatalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(sound_change)), a very common process across languages.

Typically, /k/ fronts and spirantizes to /ç/. In isolation it often goes further, to /tʃ/, but after /s/, /sç/ may coalesce to /ʃ/.

Consider, in particular, Italian, where an original Latin 'c' (/k/) before a front vowel has usually become /tʃ/ ('ci'), but after 's' it has become /ʃ/ ('sci').

Comment: An interesting case is Venetian, where some words that in Italian have retained /sk/ have /stʃ/ instead, like *s'ciao* /stʃao/, Italian *schiavo* /skjavo/ 'servant, slave' from which the salutation *ciao* /tʃao/ (originally 'I am your servant'='at your service')